# How to convert coordinates between world coordinates and screen coordinates

Tags: python, pygame, coordinates

I am using a tilemap in which I have square tiles.
Knowing that, the size of the screen and the player position(in world coordinates) how I convert between this systems? Is there any formula?

EDIT:
For example:
The top left corner is (0,0)
**player position in tiles:** (ScreenX / 2, ScreenY / 2)
**player position in screen:** always (0, 0)
**grass tile position in tiles:** (Gx, Gy)

Now the question is: how can I get the screen coordinates for the grass tile?

Comment: What do you mean with "world coordinates"?
Give us an example so we can think something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your grass tile's position in the tilemap is `<Gx,Gy>` then its pixel position in the game world will be:

```
tile_worldX = Gx * Tile_Size
tile_worldY = Gy * Tile_Size
```

Then you subtract the position of the screen's top-left corner from these coordinates to get their on-screen pixel position:

```
tile_screenX = tile_worldX - view_x
tile_screenY = tile_worldY - view_y
```

This assumes that the screen's top-left corner is 0,0 in your viewport. Sometimes game engines will move 0,0 to the middle or bottom-left of the viewport so you may have to compensate for that difference.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response but I still can't get this right. This is code to get the screen coordinates(I am using pygame): pygame.Rect(math.floor(3 / TILESIZE), math.floor(2 / TILESIZE), self.ts, self.ts), The world coordinates are (3, 2)

Comment: Can you clarify that (3,2) refers to the rows and columns in your tilemap? I believe you would need to multiply those numbers by the tile size to get the pixel coordinates.
So X = Tile_Column * Tile_Size and 
Y = Tile_Row * Tile_Size

Comment: Okay, your player is always at 0,0 on screen; Is that the top-left corner or the middle of the screen?

Comment: I reedited the question, sorry

Comment: Hello, thanks for your massive help! I now have it working, I used this: math.floor(Gx * TILESIZE) + math.floor(self.Px * TILESIZE). Feel free to update your answer to include this, but anyway I will accept it. Thanks again!